# Postgresql - dynamic naming for saving files

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to create an XML file from a table and have the name of the file be dynamic based on a prefix and the dttm of when the XML is created.  My function creates the XML file but I cannot figure out how to dynamically name the file in the following format:

xml1022161250.xml (XML | dttm.xml)

Any help is much appreciated. The function is below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION createXML() RETURNS trigger AS $createXML$
BEGIN
if new.modified_dttm is null then
COPY(select query_to_xml('select * from table where modified_dttm is null',true,true,'')) to 'c:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/xml123.xml';
RETURN new;
END IF;
END;
$createXML$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html):

```
select now(), to_char(now(), 'DDMMYYHH24MI');

              now              |  to_char   
-------------------------------+------------
 2016-10-22 19:52:57.033702+02 | 2210161952
(1 row)
```

In the function you have to use [dynamic sql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) with `execute()` and [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT), example:

```
create or replace function test()
returns void language plpgsql as $$
begin
    execute format(
        $f$
            copy (select 1) to 'c:/data/xml%s.xml'
        $f$, to_char(now(), 'DDMMYYHH24MI')
    );
end $$;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I added the execute statement to my function and it worked!